# Magento describeTable not picking up new column

Tags: php, apache, magento, caching

I added a new column to one of my tables. When I step through, Magento does not pick up the new column. I tried reindexing, I tried clearing cache. No luck. When I look in the database, I can clearly see the column is there, yet Magento is not picking up the new column. I have had to problem before, and it is really time consuming.

Comment: The problem resolved it self the first time, If I knew what the problem was I would of fixed it obviously. I figured this is a easy answer I am just missing something. If you never had this problem, then you probably know nothing about it. When you save your table, it loads the schema information. This is CORE code, nothing I wrote. So if you want to replicate the issue, go and make a simple model and save something. and look at `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_prepareDataForTable` where it loads the columns. There you will see a mismatch of columns from what is really in the database

Answer (score 1):

Magento caches database structure. Try to clear your cache. You can use a script like this:

`$app = Mage::app();
if ($app != null)
{
    $cache = $app->getCache();
    if ($cache != null)
    {
        $cache->clean('matchingTag', array('DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL'));
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Besides flushing Magento cache, my issue was that we use Redis, it needs to be flushed then as well:

```
redis-cli FLUSHALL
```